# How do you concat a string to a div class name?

Tags: html, handlebars.js, templating

For example, `<div class="hi_" + "1">`
(which doesn't work)

Use case is if I'm templating in handlebars and my code is:

```
{{#each this}}
     <div class="box_" + {{id}}>
{{/each}}
```

How would I go about naming my divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply insert the placeholder into the class attribute like so:

```
{{#each this}}
    <div class="box_{{ id }}"></div>
{{/each}}
```